# LibGDX and ScrollPane with multiple Label

Tags: android, scroll, libgdx, screen, scrollpane

I'm trying to make a play and I do the store section . I would use a scrollpane , I saw online that is quite used to the scroll elements . But I do not know why I can not make them do the slide , but in fact I left everything in the middle , as in the picture :

[image]

here is the code of the Screen:

```
@Override
    public void show() {
        this.stage = new Stage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this.stage);

        final Label text = new Label("test of scroll 1", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("kalam-regular.fnt"), false), Color.BLACK));
        text.setAlignment(Align.center);
        text.setWrap(true);
        final Label text2 = new Label("test of scroll 3", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("kalam-regular.fnt"), false), Color.BLACK));
        text2.setAlignment(Align.center);
        text2.setWrap(true);
        final Label text3 = new Label("test of scroll 3", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("kalam-regular.fnt"), false), Color.BLACK));
        text3.setAlignment(Align.center);
        text3.setWrap(true);

        final Table scrollTable = new Table();
        scrollTable.add(text);
        scrollTable.columnDefaults(0).width(500);
        scrollTable.add(text2);
        scrollTable.columnDefaults(1).width(500);
        scrollTable.add(text3);
        scrollTable.columnDefaults(2).width(500);

        final ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane(scrollTable);
        scroller.setScrollingDisabled(false, true);
        final Table table = new Table();
        table.setFillParent(true);
        table.add(scroller).fill().expand();

        backgroundPNGStatic = new Image(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.png"))));
        backgroundPNGStatic.setWidth(Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
        backgroundPNGStatic.setHeight(Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        backgroundPNGStatic.setPosition(0, 0);
        backgroundPNGStatic.setZIndex(0);

        stage.addActor(backgroundPNGStatic);
        stage.addActor(table);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        this.stage.act();
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        this.stage.draw();
    }
```

as you see the strings are above each other.
I am new to this framework , I am perhaps doing something wrong ?
I wish the outcome were the elements side by side , at the end of the development will be about 10 items .

Comment: can you explain more please what do you mean by "I'm trying to make a play"

Comment: I guess he meant "I'm trying to make a game". @question: the ScrollPane component won't scroll if there's nothing to scroll, the content needs to be bigger than it.

Comment: your code makes me weep a little inside. you should really not load a bitmap font every time you create a label.. Also, looking at the image, you have stacked the labels on top of each other. Not side by side. It might be you. Not sure if setFillParent() works with a stage, so that might be your issue. Add a .debug() to your table to see where the borders actually are.

Comment: the code was made ​​online , before I would fix that worked.
So if I understand , if I put text.setHeight ( ScreenHeight ) and text.setWidth ( ScreenWidth ) then this should work ?

Comment: The ScrollPane will allow scrolling if there's more content than what can fit in it. `text.setHeight(ScreenHeight + 1)` will probably work.